# Logging with JsonConsole prints unicode values instead of characters

Tags: c#, json, logging

I am trying to implement the `AddJsonConsole` logger to my C# API. I got it to work, but instead of special characters, it prints their Unicode value (e.g. `\u003E` instead of `>`). Is there a way to configure it, to print the actual characters?

I've set it up like this in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole(options =>  
{
    options.IncludeScopes = false;
    options.TimestampFormat = "HH:mm:ss"; 
    options.JsonWriterOptions = new() 
    { 
        Indented = true,
    };
});
```

Which gives a return like this:

```
{
  "Timestamp": "11.26.19",
  "EventId": 0,
  "LogLevel": "Error",
  "Category": "Mixorama.Server.Controllers.CocktailsController",
  "Message": "Failed to create cocktail",
  "Exception": "System.InvalidOperationException: The type of navigation \u0027CocktailEntity.Ingredients\u0027 is \u0027SelectListIterator\u003CIngredientEntity, IngredientEntity\u003E\u0027 which does not implement \u0027ICollection\u003CIngredientEntity\u003E\u0027. Collection navigations must implement \u0027ICollection\u003C\u003E\u0027 of the target type.\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ClrICollectionAccessor\u00603.GetCollection(Object instance)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ClrICollectionAccessor\u00603.GetOrCreateCollection(Object instance, Boolean forMaterialization)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ClrICollectionAccessor\u00603.Add(Object entity, Object value, Boolean forMaterialization)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.AddToCollection(INavigationBase navigationBase, Object value, Boolean forMaterialization)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.AddToCollection(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean fromQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.SetReferenceOrAddToCollection(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean fromQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.ToDependentFixup(InternalEntityEntry dependentEntry, InternalEntityEntry principalEntry, IForeignKey foreignKey, Boolean fromQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.InitialFixup(InternalEntityEntry entry, InternalEntityEntry duplicateEntry, Boolean fromQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.FireStateChanged(EntityState oldState)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable\u00601 forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable\u00601 fallbackState)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode\u00601 node)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode\u00601 node, Func\u00602 handleNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.NavigationCollectionChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase, IEnumerable\u00601 added, IEnumerable\u00601 removed)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.NavigationCollectionChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase, IEnumerable\u00601 added, IEnumerable\u00601 removed)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectNavigationChange(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.LocalDetectChanges(InternalEntityEntry entry)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectChanges(IStateManager stateManager)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.TryDetectChanges()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Mixorama.Server.Controllers.CocktailsController.CreateCocktail(CreateCocktailRequest request) in c:\\Users\\busks\\Code\\Mixorama\\Mixorama.Server\\Controllers\\CocktailsController.cs:line 75",
  "State": {
    "Message": "Failed to create cocktail",
    "{OriginalFormat}": "Failed to create cocktail"
  }
}
```

(note how the `Exception` field is full of Unicode values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.unsaferelaxedjsonescaping) as [JsonWriterOptions.Encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonwriteroptions.encoder) to restrict escaping of characters to the necessary minimum:

```
options.JsonWriterOptions = new() 
    { 
        Indented = true,
        Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
    };
```

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/character-encoding

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm with `Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`.